# Proofs with injective functions

Tags: functions

Not a general question I know, but would just like an idea of how to start off. Thanks in advance

For function
f
:
A
→
B
and subset
A'
⊆
A
let
f
(
A'
) =
{
b
∈
B
|∃
a
∈
A'
(
f
(
a
) =
b
)
}
.  Given
function
f
:
A
→
B
we define function
P
f
:
P
(
A
)
→P
(
B
)
as follows:
P
f
(
A'
) =
f
(
A'
)
for any
A'
⊆
A
. Prove the following statements:

(a)
f
:
A
→
B
is injective iff
P
f
:
P
(
A
)
→P
(
B
)
is injective.

(b)
f
:
A
→
B
is surjective iff
P
f
:
P
(
A
)
→P
(
B
)
is surjective.

Comment: Remember that for a single element $a\in A$, we have $\{a\}\in P(A)$. That is a simple and effective link.

Answer (score 0):

You start off one at a time.

So, you start by solving (a). And you notice that (a) is a "iff" statement, so you have two steps:

- Prove that if $f$ is injective, then $Pf$ is injective. That is, take any $A_1,A_2\in\mathcal P(A)$ and assume that $Pf(A_1)=Pf(A_2)$. From that, and the fact that $f$ is injective, prove that $A_1=A_2$.
- Prove that if $Pf$ is injective, then $f$ is injective (similarly as above).

Then do the same for (b).

---

Naturally, you will get stuck in places, but let's cross that bridge once you get to it.